# возможно ли определить кто подключен в групповому адресу?

Tags: linux, c, сетевое-программирование

например меня сканирует хакер. он написал сканнер, который подключился к групповому адресу, например к такому 224.0.0.0, и сканирует мой компьютер, а пакеты его содержать групповой адрес. и мой компьютер отправляет ответы на него, а так как он подключен к группе, то может видеть результаты. я точно не помню, но я читал что вроде можно отправлять в группу не являясь участником группы, а читать в группе могут только участники. так вот, как можно определить кто подключен к группе?

Comment: Учитывая, что вся подсеть 224.0.0.0/24 используется только в пределах одного широковещательного сегмента, то дальше ближайшего маршрутизатора пакеты не уйдут, а значит хакер должен быть расположен в вашем же сегменте. И это значит что никакие подписки в принципе не нужны, так как такие мультикаст пакеты получат все хосты сегмента без исключения

Comment: @xverizex "кто подключен в групповому адресу?" - не уверен, но думаю, те, кто ответит на запрос *ping -b ...*

Comment: «*такие мультикаст пакеты получат все хосты сегмента без исключения*» — а мультикаст разве ни как не управляется, дабы уменьшить нагрузку? чем же тогда локальный мультикаст отличается от широковещательного общения?

Comment: @Mike их получат только те, кто входит в группу.

Comment: @xverizex "Входит в группу" довольно натянутое понятие. Рассылка скажем по ethernet идет на мультикаствые MAC. Тупые свитчи отправят такие пакеты на все порты. А хакеру никто не мешает перемести сетевуху в promisc и видеть весь этот трафик, более ничего не делая. "Вход в группу" это всего лишь сообщение по некоторым протоколам (обычно IGMP) своему ближайшему умному свитчу "Хочу видеть", после чего свитч начинает на этот порт слать нужный трафик. Причем дальше по цепочке свитч подписку пошлет уже от своего имени, что бы вышестоящие свитчи знали, что у него есть такой клиент...

Comment: А вот что это за клиент дальше одного умного свитча уже известно не будет, никто полные списки подписчиков не пересылает. Задача протокола igmp только разрешить пропуск трафика на порт

Comment: @Fat-Zer Мультикаст от броадкаста внутри одного локального сегмента, разделенного тупыми свитчами, не умеющими (или с выключенным) igmp snooping не отличается, такие свитчи разошлют его на все порты. Основные различия начинаются уже на уровне маршрутизаторов, которые конечно без запроса подписки не будут маршрутизировать такой трафик куда попало.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за разъяснение...